# Arduino Time Library and RTC Libraries

Tags: arduino-uno, time, rtc

I am using RTClib.h and TimeLib.h with an Uno.

Have been struggling for days in understanding the various RTC libraries available and how to use them with the Arduino Time Library.

**Question 1**.
If I do not want to create a new now() object each time through the loop, how do I sync the Time Library to the RTC every x seconds?  Any time I try to use the RTClib function now.hour now.minute etc it requires me to use DateTime now = RTC.now() creating the now() object.

Is there an equivalent function in RTCLib as setSyncProvider(RTC.get) in DS1307RTC library?

Is there an equivalent to setSyncInterval(5000)

**Question 2**.
Which RTCLib should I call out? There are several used in examples:

<RTClib.h>

"RTClib"   using quotes

<RTCLib.h> with capital L

and sometimes also calling out one of these:

RTC_DS1307 RTC

or
RTC_DS1307 rtc

or
RTC_DS3231 rtc

**Question 3**
a. Are tmElements_t tm part of the DS1307RTC library?
b. Are these tm.Hour tm.Minute from the RTC?
c. Is there an equivalent in the RTClib.h ?

And finally I have posted some code below just to show my usage:

```
#include "RTClib.h" 
#include <Wire.h>   
#include <TimeLib.h>

RTC_DS1307 RTC;

void setup() {
  
Serial.begin(9600);
Wire.begin();  //sets up the I2C
RTC.begin();   //initializes the I2C to the RTC


if (! RTC.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
}
    
//  Set the RTC Time to 5:10:30 Nov 3 2020
      RTC.adjust(DateTime(2020,11,3,5,10,30));

//Set Arduino Time Library different than RTC time to see which is which
setTime(9, 27, 05, 14, 07, 2015);
      
}


 void loop() {

/*
// How do I sync Time Library to RTC after x seconds?
  setSyncProvider(RTC.get); // This is in the DS1307RTC.h Library
  setSyncInterval(5000);   //  Are there such functions in RTClib ?
*/

DateTime now = RTC.now();   // Pulls RTC time into now().  Does not sync with Time Library
                            // Do not want to do this every loop.

//Print RTC Time
Serial.println();
Serial.print("RTC now.hour        ");
Serial.println(now.hour());
Serial.print("RTC now.minute      ");
Serial.println(now.minute());
Serial.print("RTC now.second:     ");
Serial.println(now.second());
Serial.println();
Serial.println();


//Print Arduino TimeLib Time
Serial.print("Time Lib Hour:       "); 
Serial.print(hour());  
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Time Lib Min:        "); 
Serial.print(minute());  
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Time Lib Sec:        "); 
Serial.print(second());  
Serial.println();
Serial.println();

delay(1000);
  
 }
```

---

Updated 5 Nov 2020

I think I almost  understand.
Please let me know if this code is doing what I think it is doing, specifically:

In Setup:
Set the RTC to 5:10:30.
Set Time Library to 9:27:05 with setTime().
Set Time Library to RTC time with DateTime now (over writing   9:27:05)?
Set Time Library variables to RTC using tm.Hour = now.Hour, etc.

In Loop:
Every 5 seconds update hour(), minute() second() with RTC time.
Every loop update tm.hour with hour(), etc.

I know it is still not right since the serial prints show tm.Hour,tm.Minute alternating each loop as shown at the bottom.

```cpp
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>

RTC_DS1307 RTC;

time_t time_provider()
{
    return RTC.now().unixtime();
}

tmElements_t tm;  //part of Time Library

void setup() {
    //setSyncProvider(time_provider);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Wire.begin();  //sets up the I2C
    RTC.begin();   //initializes the I2C to the RTC

    if (! RTC.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    }

    //  Set the RTC Time to 5:10:30 Nov 3 2020
    RTC.adjust(DateTime(2020,11,3,5,10,30));

    //Set Arduino Time Library different than RTC time 9:27:05
    setTime(9, 27, 05, 14, 07, 2015);

    //Setting Time Library to RTC time
    DateTime now = RTC.now();
    tm.Hour = now.hour();
    tm.Minute = now.minute();
    tm.Second = now.second();
}


void loop() {
    setSyncProvider(RTC.now);
    setSyncInterval(5000);

    //Time Library time updates to RTC every 5 seconds
    tm.Hour = hour();
    tm.Minute = minute();
    tm.Second = second();

    Serial.print("tm.Hour:    ");
    Serial.print(tm.Hour);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("tm.Minute:  ");
    Serial.print(tm.Minute);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("tm.Seconds: ");
    Serial.print(tm.Second);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
}
```

Serial Prints:

```
tm.Hour:    5
tm.Minute:  34
tm.Seconds: 56

tm.Hour:    18
tm.Minute:  0
tm.Seconds: 0

tm.Hour:    5
tm.Minute:  34
tm.Seconds: 56

tm.Hour:    18
tm.Minute:  0
tm.Seconds: 0

tm.Hour:    5
tm.Minute:  34
tm.Seconds: 56

tm.Hour:    18
tm.Minute:  0
tm.Seconds: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me first give some background about these libraries.

The Time library uses `millis()` for timekeeping. Since this can be
subject to significant drift, it provides a means to periodically sync
to an external time provider. Hence the functions `setSyncProvider()`
and `setSyncInterval()`.

RTClib is meant to interface an RTC. It does not provide timekeeping on
its own: you get the current time by querying an RTC through it's
`now()` method.

These two libraries can nicely complement each other, as RTClib can be
used as a time provider for the Time library:

```cpp
// Provide the RTC time to the Time library.
time_t time_provider() {
    return RTC.now().unixtime();
}

void setup() {
    // ...
    setSyncProvider(time_provider);
}
```

> If I do not want to create a new now() object [...]

It is actually called a `DateTime` object.

> Is there an equivalent [to `tmElements_t`] in the RTClib

Yes, the [`DateTime` class](https://adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_date_time.html). Note that, unlike the
`tmElements_t` structure, the data fields of `DateTime` are not public,
and you have to use accessors to get them: `year()`, `month()`,
`day()`...

**Alternative timekeeping method**

Since you are using an Arduino Uno, there is a third method of
timekeeping you may want to consider. Instead of querying the RTC on
every loop iteration (RTClib) or interpolating the RTC readings with
`millis()` (Time library), you may route a 1 Hz output of the RTC
to an interrupt pin, and count the seconds in the ISR. The [avr-libc
timing code](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html) is designed to provide timekeeping in this
fashion. It all boils down to:

```cpp
// Initialize the system time from the RTC.
set_system_time(RTC.now().secondstime());

// Keep the time in sync using the 1 Hz output of the RTC.
pinMode(pin1Hz, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin1Hz), system_tick, FALLING);
```

For more details, see the example sketch [interrupts1Hz.ino](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/1.12.0/examples/interrupts1Hz/interrupts1Hz.ino)
provided with RTClib.

---

**Edit 1**: Answering a comment

> which pin does [the Arduino interrupt pin] connect to on the RTC?

It depends on the RTC you are using. I will assume it's a DS1307, as
implied by the code in your question. Take a look at the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf)
of the RTC. On page 6, there is a table titled “Pin description”. From
this table:

> **pin**: 7
> **name**: SQW/OUT
> **function**: Square Wave/Output Driver. When enabled, the SQWE bit
> set to 1, the SQW/OUT pin outputs one of four square-wave frequencies
> (1Hz, 4kHz, 8kHz, 32kHz). The SQW/OUT pin is open drain and requires
> an external pullup resistor. SQW/OUT operates with either
> V<sub>CC</sub> or V<sub>BAT</sub> applied. The pullup voltage can be
> up to 5.5V regardless of the voltage on V<sub>CC</sub>. If not used,
> this pin can be left floating.

If you are using an RTC *module*, you will have to figure out where this
pin is exposed on the module's connector.

In any case, you will have to enable the 1 Hz square wave output with

```cpp
RTC.writeSqwPinMode(DS1307_SquareWave1HZ);
```

---

**Edit 2**: Commenting on the update to the question:

> ```cpp
> // Set the RTC Time to 5:10:30 Nov 3 2020
> RTC.adjust(DateTime(2020,11,3,5,10,30));
> ```

Correct.

> ```cpp
> // Set Arduino Time Library different than RTC time 9:27:05
> setTime(9, 27, 05, 14, 07, 2015);
> ```

Correct. Date is 2015-07-14.

> ```cpp
> // Setting Time Library to RTC time
> DateTime now = RTC.now();
> tm.Hour = now.hour();
> tm.Minute = now.minute();
> tm.Second = now.second();
> ```

No. This is only partially initializing the `tm` variable. It has no
effect on the idea the Time library has of the current time. Note that
the date fields of `tm` have not been initialized at this point, and
could well be invalid (like month 23, day 125).

> ```cpp
> setSyncProvider(RTC.now);
> ```

This is incorrect, and should have generated a compiler warning.
`setSyncProvider()` expects a function that returns the current time as
Unix time (a simple integer, of type `time_t`). You are providing a
function that returns the current time in broken down form (year,
month...), with type `DateTime`. The Time library will not understand
that and may yield garbage like, say, 18:00:00.

The time returned by `RTC.now()` can be converted to Unix time with the
`unixtime()` method. That's why I gave you the `time_provider()`
function.

Also, you are not supposed to call `setSyncProvider()` and
`setSyncInterval()` on every loop iteration. Do it once and for all in
`setup()`.

> ```cpp
> // Time Library time updates to RTC every 5 seconds
> tm.Hour = hour();
> tm.Minute = minute();
> tm.Second = second();
> ```

Again, this is only updating the variable `tm`. It has no effect on what
the Time library believes is the current time.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an equivalent function in RTCLib as setSyncProvider(RTC.get) in DS1307RTC library?
>
> Is there an equivalent to setSyncInterval(5000)

Those are TimeLib functions. There's no "equivalent to" since you *are* using TimeLib.

The first one just expects a pointer to a function that returns a `time_t`. What is in that function is up to you.

> Which RTCLib should I call out? There are several used in examples:

The capitalisation should match the name of the header file. Windows doesn't care, and OS X usually doesn't care, but can be configured to. Linux *does* care and needs it to match. If you want your code to be portable then you must keep the capitalisation the same as the file.

> and sometimes also calling out one of these:

You need to create an object that matches your physical RTC.

> a. Are tmElements_t tm part of the DS1307RTC library?

No. They are part of TimeLib.

> b. Are these tm.Hour tm.Minute from the RTC?

They are whatever gets assigned to them by a function that is called. They are just variables. They can contain anything.

> c. Is there an equivalent in the RTClib.h ?

No. But then you don't need there to be if you're using TimeLib.

So: you need to

- Create a function that gets the time from the RTC through whatever library you want to use (RTCLib for example) and calculates the number of seconds since 00:00:00 01/01/1970, which it then returns as a `time_t`.
- Pass that to TimeLib's `setSyncProvider()`
- Set a sync frequency with `setSyncInterval()`.

Comment: -I have read much about these libraries and still confused.  Thanks for your help.  Couple follow ups:  1. Does function now.hour() get time from RTC?  2.  Does hour() get time from Time Library? 3. Does setSyncProvider() set  hour() to the RTC ?

Comment: `now` is the time from the RTC at the moment you assign the `now` object. `.hour()` is just the hour contained inside that object. `hour()` is the time from the TimeLib library, yes. setSyncProvider() doesn't send anything to the RTC, it gets the time from the RTC on a regular basis and updates the TimeLib with the current time.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet - Using interrupt pin looks very nice and clean. If Pin 2 is used on Arduino for the interrupt, which pin does Pin 2 connect to  on the RTC?  I assume it is in addition to the SCL and SDA pins (?).

Comment: "setSyncProvider() doesn't send anything to the RTC, it gets the time from the RTC on a regular basis and updates the TimeLib with the current time."    Yes, so If hour() is the time from the TimeLib Library then setSyncProvider() makes hour() equal to RTC hour?

Comment: It's a little more complex than that. TimeLib uses `millis()` to keep track of the time. It regularly updates its internal idea of what the time is depending on `setSyncInterval()`. when you ask for `hour()`, if more time has passed since it last got the real time that you specified in `setSyncInterval()` it will go and get the time from the RTC. Otherwise it will just tell you what it *thinks* the time is according to its own internal calculations.

Comment: I updated my post with help provided. Almost have it understood.

Comment: Why does output alternate values for tm.hour, etc?  See bottom of updated question. thanks

Comment: Because you're constantly changing the sync provider and interval. You set those once and once only in setup, and never again.

Comment: Thanks that worked.    Looking at my updated code, to make sure I am not deceiving myself, are the outputs of  tm.Hour tm.Minute. tm.Second  Time Library values which are updated from the RTC  every 5 seconds ?  And am I not creating an Object every loop?

Comment: That looks right, yes. Though you don't need the `tmElements_t` struct at all since all you're dealing with is simple numbers. `tmElements_t` is just a convenient way of bundling them all together if you want to pass it to another function. Just `Serial.print(hour());`

Comment: thanks for all of your help.  I will post the final code as an answer for anyone else needing to learn this.