# Sync of Time Library and RTClib

Tags: arduino-uno, time, rtc

Trying to understand the two libraries and setSyncProvider(RTC.now).
Using Arduino Uno with Adafruit ChronoDot.  Aduino IDE 1.8.13.

The code below is simply to understand what is happening.
I am getting surprising results which means I do not understand what the libraries are doing.

What I *think* I am telling it to do:

1. Set time RTC to 05:10:30
2. Set Time Library to 09:27:05
3. In Loop, printing Library time (hour, minute, seconds)
4. In Loop, printing RTC time (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
5. Every 5 seconds sync the Time Library to the RTC.
   This is not what it is doing.
   The output from serial prints is at the bottom.

**Question 1:**  Why does Time Library time  hour() minute() second() change from 9:27:9 to 12:43:44 after first sync and then from 12:43:48 to 19:1:20 after second sync, then reseting to  19:1:20 after each subsequent sync?

**Question 2:**  After the Sync, why is Time Library hour(), minute() and second() not set to RTC values of now.hour(), now.minute() and now.second()?

```
#include "RTClib.h"  
#include <Wire.h>  
#include <TimeLib.h>  
  
RTC_DS1307 RTC;  
unsigned long LastSyncTime = 0;    //will control when it syncs just to understand   
  
time_t time_provider()  

{  
    return RTC.now().unixtime();    
}  

  
void setup() {  
Serial.begin(9600);  
Wire.begin();  //sets up the I2C  
RTC.begin();   //initializes the I2C to the RTC  
  
//  Set the RTC Time to 5:10:30 Nov 3 2020  
RTC.adjust(DateTime(2020,11,3,5,10,30));  

//Set Arduino Time Library different than RTC time 9:27:05 so see how sync works  
setTime(9, 27, 05, 4, 07, 2015);  

}  


void loop() {  

//Sync time every 5 seconds  
if ((millis() - LastSyncTime) > 5000)  
  {  
  Serial.println("+++++   Sync  ++++++++");  
  setSyncProvider(RTC.now);  //sets Time Library to RTC time: hour() set to RTC now.hour (?)  
  LastSyncTime = millis();  
  
   }  


DateTime now = RTC.now();  // gets RTC time into now Object  
  
//Print Time Lib Times  
Serial.print("hour:       ");  
Serial.print(hour());  
Serial.println();  
Serial.print("minute:     ");  
Serial.print(minute());  
Serial.println();  
Serial.print("seconds:    ");  
Serial.print(second());  
Serial.println();  
Serial.println();    

  
    
//Print RTC time  
Serial.print("now.hour:   ");  
Serial.print(now.hour());  
Serial.println();  
Serial.print("now.minute: ");  
Serial.print(now.minute());  
Serial.println();  
Serial.print("now.second: ");  
Serial.print(now.second());  
Serial.println();  
Serial.println("______________________");    
  
delay(1000);  
}
```

OUTPUT

hour:       9
minute:     27
seconds:    8

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 33

hour:       9
minute:     27
seconds:    9

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 34

+++++   Sync  ++++++++
hour:       12
minute:     43
seconds:    44

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 35

hour:       12
minute:     43
seconds:    45

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 36

hour:       12
minute:     43
seconds:    46

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 37

hour:       12
minute:     43
seconds:    47

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 38

hour:       12
minute:     43
seconds:    48

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 39

+++++   Sync  ++++++++
hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    20

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 40

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    21

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 41

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    22

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 42

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    23

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 43

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    24

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 44

+++++   Sync  ++++++++
hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    20

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 45

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    21

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 46

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    22

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 47

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    23

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 48

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    24

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 49

+++++   Sync  ++++++++
hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    20

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 50

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    21

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 51

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    22

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 52

hour:       19
minute:     1
seconds:    23

now.hour:   5
now.minute: 10
now.second: 53

Comment: −1, as you visibly did not pay attention to [an answer to your previous question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/79055). I already explained why `setSyncProvider(RTC.now)` is incorrect and can only result in the Time library giving you garbage.

Comment: @EdgarBonet - Sorry I did use your previous information and it did work. Copy paste error here from older code. Thanks for your help and  patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Time Library time hour() minute() second() change from 9:27:9 to 12:43:44 after first sync and then from 12:43:48 to 19:1:20 after second sync, then reseting to 19:1:20 after each subsequent sync?

Because:

1. You keep calling `setSyncProvider()`. The whole point of the sync system is that **you should only call that once to set the sync provider and then it syncs itself *automatically***.
2. You are setting the sync provider to a function that returns an object. The sync provider needs a function that returns an unsigned long (`time_t`).

Your code should be:

```cpp
setSyncProvider(time_provider);
```

And it should **only be called once from inside setup**.

> Question 2: After the Sync, why is Time Library hour(), minute() and second() not set to RTC values of now.hour(), now.minute() and now.second()?

Because of all the things I stated above and were also told in your last question.